# TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined On Tabs

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to show tabs using the dropdown. The tabs work fine but the error is still there and when I select a tab menu in the dropdown it doesn't close the drop-down menu but it shows the corresponding tab and the error shows up.

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle dropdown-tabs" style="background-color: #fdcd3d; color: #000;" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Achievers
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        <li id="#achiever" name="Achievers">
            <a class="dropdown-link" name="#achiever" data-toggle="tab" href="#achiever" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-expanded="true">Achievers</a>
        </li>
        <li id="#articles" name="Articles">
            <a class="dropdown-link" name="#articles" data-toggle="tab" href="#articles" role="tab" aria-controls="profile">Articles</a>
        </li>
        <li id="#bulletins" name="Bulletins">
            <a class="dropdown-link" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="profile">Bulletins</a>
        </li> 
        <li id="#events" name="Events">
            <a class="dropdown-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#events" role="tab" aria-controls="profile">Events</a>
        </li>             
        <li id="#jobs" name="Jobs">
            <a class="dropdown-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#jobs" role="tab" aria-controls="profile">Jobs</a>
        </li>                 

    </ul>
</div>
```

my code for the js dropdown menu

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.dropdown-menu > li > a').click(function(e){
        var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        var text = $(this).parent().attr('name');
        // var tab = $('.tab-pane').attr('id');
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.dropdown-tabs').text(text);

        if(id != null){
            $('a[href="' + id + '"]').tab('show');
        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The id must start with `a-z` or `A-Z` and cannot begin with `#`.

Then in `$('a[href="' + id + '"]').tab('show');`, you would need to change to `$('a[href="#' + id + '"]').tab('show');`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown-menu > a').click(function(e){
    var text = $(this).text();
    $('.dropdown-toggle').text(text);
    $(this).tab('show');
    $(this).removeClass("active");
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" style="background-color: #fdcd3d; color: #000;" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Bulletins
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#bulletins_tab">Bulletins</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#events_tab">Events</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#jobs_tab">Jobs</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="bulletins_tab" class="tab-pane active">
      <h3>bulletins</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="events_tab" class="tab-pane">
      <h3>events</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="jobs_tab" class="tab-pane">
      <h3>jobs</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thats the first thing i did. But it also gives the same error so I put "#" in the id of the element and the tabs start showing

Comment: @Dn6Dn Is this what you've wanted?

Comment: sir i noticed that you're using bootstrap 3. I am using bootstrap 4 so the code doesnt work and still return the same error ill update my question sorry forgot to include bootstrap version and the dropdown needed the popper.js

Comment: I mean my current code is displaying the correct tab but the error still shows up

Comment: @Dn6Dn try this one. This is now Bootstrap 4.

Comment: I put your codes inside my page but its not working to me. I dont know where the problem could be. The error still the same :(

Comment: I would recommend to try to use my code as a starting point because it works and gradually change my code into yours to see what causes the problem.